# Mediawiki 1.21 - remove dir="ltr" from <html>

Tags: html, translation, mediawiki

Because of the translation engine we are using, I need to remove this tag from the `<html>`.  Right now it reads

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">
```

I need it to read

```
<html lang="en" class="client-nojs">
```

The reason is for rtl languages, this tag is messing things up.  All of this is already handled in the translation engine we are using.  Any ideas?

Comment: So you're saying that the translation engine isn't working properly and you want to modify your instance of MediaWiki to work around that bug? Have you considered fixing the issue in the translation engine? (If it's not open source, you can most likely ask the developers to do it.)

Comment: Well, the developers are telling me that it's on me to fix, and I can find no way to get around this in mediawiki as I do very little work on this plateform

Answer (score 1):

I could do this by changing includes/OutputPage.php. There is a line

```
$ret = Html::htmlHeader( array( 'lang' => $this->getLanguage()->getHtmlCode(), 'dir' => $userdir, 'class' => 'client-nojs' ) );
```

I replaced

```
'dir' => $userdir
```

by

```
'dir' => ''
```

and now my page source code reads

```
<html lang="en" dir="" class="client-nojs">
```

See any page on http://www.linuxintro.org, this is where I changed it. You can also leave off 'dir' => '', completely.